# FindBy in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want find models from store. I try :
In route:

```
MyApp.EventTalksRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    MyApp.get('store').findBy('type', 'workshop')
    MyApp.store.findBy('type', 'workshop')
    Em.computed.findBy('type', 'workshop')
```

Also in controller:

```
MyApp.EventTalksController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  model: ->
    MyApp.computed.findBy('type', 'presentation')
    workshops: Em.computed.findBy('type', 'workshop')
```

And in view:

```
MyApp.EventTalksView = Ember.View.extend
  findBy: ['type', 'workshop']
  model: ->
    Ember.get('store').findBy('type', 'workshop')
```

But it's not working.. In console I have "findBy is not a function"?

Answer (score 1):

First reason:
I uses findBy.. I should used filterBy..

Second:
I used content:

```
  MyApp.TalkGroupTabsView content=model.talkGroups
```

and then I must use

```
MyApp.TalkGroup = DS.Model.extend
  workshops: Em.computed.filterBy 'talksSorted', 'type', 'workshop'
```

Quest complete :)